# Customize URLs in With Structure Navigation Tags (or How to Keep Top Level URL Segments Out of Children URLs)?

Tags: structure, navigation, children

First time using Structure on a project...

With the latest versions of Structure and EE, using the {exp:structure:nav} tag, is there a way to keep the parent entry URL segment from appearing?

That is, I have a top-level navigation menu called about which haas things like links to the newsletter and staff. With the code I have in place, the URLs for those pages are along the lines of:

http://example.com/about/newsletters
http://example.com/committees/charity

What I'd like those URLs to be is simply:

```
http://example.com/newsletters  
http://example.com/committees/charity
```

This would give the client (a large site with hundreds if not thousands of pages) an easy way to self-manage their site navigation by using Structure more as a way to group and organize menu and sub-menu items. It would have the side effect of allowing us to keep the old URL structure saving us from having to account for redirects and other broken links.

This is the code I'm using to generate my About menu:

```
<li id="nabout"><a href="{site_url}about">About Us<span class="ndrop">&#187;</span></a>
<ul>
  {exp:structure:nav start_from="/about" show_depth="2" include_ul="no" show_overview="yes" add_span="yes" has_children_class="yes" rename_overview="title"}
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Well, if you don't have tons of about pages you could do individual .htaccess rewrites. Hack solution but it would work.

Comment: On a smaller site, yeah, that would work, but this project will have several hundred to over a thousand individual pages. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I run a site with over 10,000 pages, and if this weren't the weekend I'd probably have a better thought for you. I think we just have channels that aren't in Structure, and you can use template routes.